# tikz: Expand rectangle size to cover text inside rectangle fully

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I've defined the following command that just draws four colored rectangles with some text inside them:

```
\newcommand{\fourcards}[4]{
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{cccc}
            \centering
            \tikz \draw[fill=green!50] (0,0) rectangle (1,1) node[pos=.5] {#1}; &
             \tikz \draw[fill=magenta] (0, 0) rectangle(1, 1) node[pos=.5]{#2}; & 
            \tikz \draw[fill=orange] (0, 0) rectangle(1, 1) node[pos=.5]{#3}; & 
            \tikz \draw[fill=yellow] (0, 0) rectangle(1, 1) node[pos=.5]{#4};
        \end{tabular}   
    \end{figure}
}
```

I was wondering if there was some way to change the dimensions of the rectangles dynamically, such that they accommodate the text inside them. I have found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168640/expanding-a-tikz-rectangle-to-fill-remaining-text-width) thread discussing something similar, but the OP there requires that the rectangle follows constraints imposed **outside** the rectangle: I want the rectangle to adjust itself to constraints **inside** it.

Comment: you could use a `tabular` for this

Answer (score 4):

That's what a `node` does, and it can have a fill. What's the purpose of the `figure` environment?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\fourcards}[4]{%
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{cccc}
            \tikz \node[draw,fill=green!50] {#1}; &
             \tikz \node[draw,fill=magenta] {#2}; & 
            \tikz \node[draw,fill=orange] {#3}; & 
            \tikz \node[draw,fill=yellow] {#4};
        \end{tabular}   
    \end{figure}%
}
\begin{document}
\fourcards{TexT}{Lorem upsum}{Whatnot}{woooooooord}
\end{document}
```

Slightly different approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\fourcards}[4]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style={text depth=3pt,text height=10pt}]
\matrix [ampersand replacement=\&,column sep=5pt] {
\node[draw,fill=green!50] {#1}; \&
\node[draw,fill=magenta] {#2}; \& 
\node[draw,fill=orange] {#3}; \& 
\node[draw,fill=yellow] {#4}; \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\fourcards{TexT}{Lorem upsum}{Whatnot}{woooooooord}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, that worked famously, thanks. The only reason for me to use the `figure` environment is because I needed an enveloping `float` for the `tabular` environment to control the placement better. It could've been a `table` instead.