# Expanding a Tikz rectangle to fill remaining column width

Tags: tikz-pgf, tabularx, width

Building on the (more complex) example of [Expanding a Tikz rectangle to fill remaining text width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168640/expanding-a-tikz-rectangle-to-fill-remaining-text-width), how could the blue `tikz` rectangle in the following MWE be assigned a width of (**column width** *minus* **text** (in this example: "Some Subtitle") ?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

%%%

\mdfdefinestyle{my_style_bla}{%
     linecolor=red,middlelinewidth=0.7pt, frametitlebackgroundcolor=red, apptotikzsetting={\tikzset{mdfframetitlebackground/.append style={%
shade,left color=red, right color=white}}}
}

%%%
 \newlength{\mycustomlength}
\settowidth\mycustomlength{abcdefghijklmnop}
%%%

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{mdframed}[style=my_style_bla,frametitle=\color{white}{Some Title}, nobreak=false]

%%%
%\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} >{\NoMicrotype}l X@{}}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}*{1}{p{\mycustomlength}}*{1}{X}@{}} % sub-headings modification
%%%

 & \textsc{Some Subtitle} \tikz[baseline=-0.5ex] \shade[left color=white, right color=white, middle color=blue] (0,0) rectangle (3,-0.05);
\\

%%%%%%
bla bla & \textbf{Item Title} \\
&\emph{yada yada description}
\\
\\
%%%%%%%
\end{tabularx}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

---

This is (roughly) what I'd like it to look like in this example:

[image]

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

You just have to measure the width of the text and subtract it from `\linewidth`.  Normally one would use `\dimexpr`, but since TikZ runs everything through `\pgfmathparse`, you don't need it here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

%%%

\mdfdefinestyle{my_style_bla}{%
     linecolor=red,middlelinewidth=0.7pt, frametitlebackgroundcolor=red, apptotikzsetting={\tikzset{mdfframetitlebackground/.append style={%
shade,left color=red, right color=white}}}
}

%%%
 \newlength{\mycustomlength}
\settowidth\mycustomlength{abcdefghijklmnop}
%%%

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{mdframed}[style=my_style_bla,frametitle=\color{white}{Some Title}, nobreak=false]

%%%
%\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} >{\NoMicrotype}l X@{}}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}*{1}{p{\mycustomlength}}*{1}{X}@{}} % sub-headings modification
%%%

 & \sbox0{\textsc{Some Subtitle}}\usebox0 \tikz[baseline=-0.5ex] \shade[left color=white, right color=white, middle color=blue]
   (0,0) rectangle ({\linewidth-\wd0},-0.05);
\\

%%%%%%
bla bla & \textbf{Item Title} \\
&\emph{yada yada description} \\
\\
%%%%%%%
\end{tabularx}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: what is `\sbox`, `usebox` and `\wd` ?

Comment: \savebox and \sbox create a box similar to \mbox, but save it in a box register. Registers 0-9 are not used by LaTeX itself, although it is safer to use them locally (inside a group). \usebox displays a box previously saved. More to the point, \wd, \ht and \dp return the width, height and depth of the box. Macros like \settowidth and \widthof actually use saveboxes to get the widths.